# Display descendants tags as tag in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

## I want to display the some particular descendants tags as tags in XSLT output:

## I have some xml similar to the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='item-jerd.xsl'?>
<article xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:lang="en" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" article-type="research-article">
<front id="meta">
<article-meta id="art">
<contrib-group>
<affiliation id="affiliation1">Production Engineering,<institution-wrap><institution>Engineering and Technology</institution></institution-wrap><city>Dhanga</city><country country="IN">India</country></affiliation>
<affiliation id="affiliation2">Industrial and Production Engineering,<institution-wrap><institution>India University of Engineering and Technology</institution></institution-wrap><city>Dukka</city><country country="IN">India</country></affiliation>
<affiliation id="affiliation3">Industrial Systems Engineering,<institution-wrap><institution>University of Regina</institution></institution-wrap><city>Regina</city>, Saskatchewan,<country country="CA">Canada</country></affiliation>
</contrib-group>
<author-notes>
<corresp id="cor1">GBWIN is the owner and can be contacted at:<ext-link ext-link-type="email" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="mailto:bwin@gmail.com">bwin@gmail.com</ext-link></corresp>
</author-notes>
</article-meta>
</front>
<body/>
</article>
```

## I used the below xslt condition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>HELP ME</title>
</head>
<body onkeyup="keyDown=0" onkeydown="keyDown=1">
<div class="content" id="main">
<xsl:call-template name="main"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="journalStylesheet/baseData" name="main">
<h1>Author info</h1>
<table  border="1" width="1200" bgcolor="#CCFFCC">      
<xsl:for-each select="//affiliation">
<tr>
<td width="5%">
<font class="head3">
<xsl:variable name="attr" select="./@id" />
<xsl:if test="$attr">                               
<a name="{$attr}">
<xsl:value-of select="$attr"/>
</a>                                
</xsl:if>
</font>
</td>
<td width="95%">
<font class="head3">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</font>
</td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
<h2>Author Notes</h2>
<table  border="1" width="1200" bgcolor="#CCFFCC"> 
<xsl:for-each select="//author-notes/*"><tr>
<td width="40%" class="head3">Author-notes</td>
<td width="60%" class="head3">
<xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## I want the HTML output of affiliation and author notes tags like below

```
Production Engineering,<institution-wrap><institution>Engineering and Technology</institution></institution-wrap><city>Dhanga</city><country country="IN">India</country><br />
Industrial and Production Engineering,<institution-wrap><institution>India University of Engineering and Technology</institution></institution-wrap><city>Dukka</city><country country="IN">India</country><br />
Industrial Systems Engineering,<institution-wrap><institution>University of Regina</institution></institution-wrap><city>Regina</city>, Saskatchewan,<country country="CA">Canada</country>
```

## but getting the output as

Production Engineering,Engineering and TechnologyDhangaIndia
Industrial and Production Engineering,India University of Engineering and TechnologyDukkaIndia
Industrial Systems Engineering,University of ReginaRegina, Saskatchewan,Canada

Tags should be displayed in html for output

Comment: You seem to want to serialize the elements, XSLT 3 has a `serialize` function, in earlier versions of XSLT you need to use an extension if the processor supports it or you need to write or include XSLT code that does the job, like https://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT-1.0 you can achieve this with the (not always implemented) `disable-output-escaping="yes"` attribute of `xsl:value-of`.
So apply the following modifications:

1. Change the calling template to call sub-templates with a `mode` modifier and add an `xsl:if` for adding the final `<br>` tags:

   ```
   ...
   <td width="95%">
       <font class="head3">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="serialize" />
           <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
               <br />
           </xsl:if>
       </font>
   </td>
   ...
   ```
2. Add the following templates to handle the sub-elements in this mode:

   ```
   <!-- Remove leading and trailing spaces from each text() node -->
   <xsl:template match="text()" mode="serialize">
       <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Skip all attributes in this mode because they are handled otherwise -->
   <xsl:template match="@*" mode="serialize" />

   <!-- Recreate all elements in this mode -->
   <xsl:template match="*" mode="serialize">
       <!-- ReCreate the current element tag -->
       <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat('&lt;',name())" />
       <!-- Copy the attributes of the current element -->
       <xsl:if test="@*">
           <xsl:value-of select="' '" />
           <xsl:for-each select="@*">
               <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),'=&quot;',.,'&quot;')" />
           </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:if>
       <!-- Close the opening element -->
       <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="'&gt;'" />
       <!-- Apply all sub-nodes -->
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="serialize" />
       <!-- ReCreate the closing element tag -->
       <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat('&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
   </xsl:template>
   ```

Part of its output is:

```
...
<table border="1" width="1200" bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
  <tr>
    <td width="5%">
        <font class="head3">
            <a name="affiliation1">affiliation1</a>
        </font>
    </td>
    <td width="95%">
        <font class="head3">
            Production Engineering,
            <institution-wrap>
                <institution>Engineering and Technology</institution>
            </institution-wrap>
            <city>Dhanga</city>
            <country country="IN">India</country>
            <br>
        </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="5%">
        <font class="head3">
            <a name="affiliation2">affiliation2</a>
        </font>
    </td>
    <td width="95%">
        <font class="head3">
                Industrial and Production Engineering,
                <institution-wrap>
                    <institution>India University of Engineering and Technology</institution>
                </institution-wrap>
                <city>Dukka</city>
                <country country="IN">India</country>
                <br>
            </font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="5%">
            <font class="head3">
                <a name="affiliation3">affiliation3</a>
            </font>
        </td>
        <td width="95%">
            <font class="head3">
                    Industrial Systems Engineering,
                    <institution-wrap>
                        <institution>University of Regina</institution>
                    </institution-wrap>
                    <city>Regina</city>
                    , Saskatchewan,<country country="CA">Canada</country>
            </font>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
...
```

which is close to what you desired. The `<br />` tags are displayed as `<br>` tags due to the output method HTML.

---

The whole XSLT-1.0 code that incorporates the above improvement would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>HELP ME</title>
            </head>
            <body onkeyup="keyDown=0" onkeydown="keyDown=1">
                <div class="content" id="main">
                    <xsl:call-template name="main"/>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="journalStylesheet/baseData" name="main">
        <h1>Author info</h1>
        <table  border="1" width="1200" bgcolor="#CCFFCC">      
            <xsl:for-each select="//affiliation">
                <tr>
                    <td width="5%">
                        <font class="head3">
                            <xsl:variable name="attr" select="./@id" />
                            <xsl:if test="$attr">                               
                                <a name="{$attr}">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$attr"/>
                                </a>

                            </xsl:if>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="95%">
                        <font class="head3">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="serialize" />
                            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                                <br />
                            </xsl:if>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        <h2>Author Notes</h2>
        <table  border="1" width="1200" bgcolor="#CCFFCC"> 
            <xsl:for-each select="//author-notes/*"><tr>
                    <td width="40%" class="head3">Author-notes</td>
                    <td width="60%" class="head3">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="serialize">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Skip all attributes in this mode because they are handled otherwise -->
    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="serialize" />

    <!-- Recreate all elements in this mode -->
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="serialize">
        <!-- ReCreate the current element tag -->
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat('&lt;',name())" />
        <!-- Copy the attributes of the current element -->
        <xsl:if test="@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="' '" />
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),'=&quot;',.,'&quot;')" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
        <!-- Close the opening element -->
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="'&gt;'" />
        <!-- Apply all sub-nodes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="serialize" />
        <!-- ReCreate the closing element tag -->
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat('&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I tried as you mentioned but was not able to obtain the desired output. If it is possible by you to share the whole modified xslt file to me.

Comment: @Yogib: I added the whole code to the answer. (And sorry for the delay).

Comment: yes exactly the same i tested with your code but not getting the tags in output. Is there any browser rendering issue.

Comment: (Unfortunately) Yes. Try to "toggle the value of the `about:config` setting `privacy.file_unique_origin`. Doing so resolved my page load issue[...]" Read about the whole desaster [here](https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1264318).

Comment: The above fix is valid for Firefox. I do not know about Chrome or Safari. But they may have a fix for them, too.